# How do file systems allocate space for files? Is it a bin packing problem?

Tags: filesystems, bin-packing

I used to work on software for manufacturing stuff out of wood, glass, stone etc. and provided means to automatically lay out parts minimizing waste. Many of you know this as bin packing problem. I stumbled upon this - http://www.dropbox.com/jobs/challenges#packing-your-dropbox - and found the problem interesting.

The disk space is usually thought of as a 1d array, and files are broken apart to fit between each other. Here, however, they're non-overlapping rectangles. I use an app Disk Inventory X, it uses the same concept for file system visualization.

Pardon my ignorance and inability to properly construct a google query, can someone please explain me, how does this relate to real-world implementations?

Assuming this is the way files are layed out on a disk, what are the real world requirements for input data and time/memory consumed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "It depends upon file system" :-) I would look for course lectures/notes first. [Here is a very coarse PPT](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~sponnu1/File_system.ppt) presentation. *Many* better google results for "filesystem free list lecture" (entire first page is highly relevant; it helps to know the right keywords). Happy reading.